# Как можно проще нарисовать радиальный градиент?

Tags: c++, градиент

Есть ли способ проще, чем просто рисовать 240 кругов разного цвета и радиуса? И как рассчитать точное количество пикселей, нужное для каждого круга, вместо того, что бы отрисовывать по 320*240 пикселей? Пробовал

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cv::Mat mat(240, 320, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));

    for (int r = 0; r < 240; ++r) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 320 * 240; ++i) {
            int x = r * sin(i) + 160;
            int y = r * cos(i) + 120;

            if (x < 320 && y < 240 && x > 0 && y > 0) {
                mat.at<uchar>(y, x) = 255 - r * 1.25;
            }
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("img", mat);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проходить один раз по каждому пикселю в прямоугольнике, и высчитывать цвет исходя из расстояния до центра?

Comment: Разумеется, лучше не рисовать никакие круги, а сканировать пиксели вашего 320*240 и вычислять значение для каждого пиксела на основе расстояния до центра. Можно воспользоваться 8-сторонней симметрией для оптимизации, т.е. фактически сканировать только 1/8 прямоугольника. Ваш способ с кругами фактически неработоспособен, ибо не гарантирует попадания во все пикселы.